# Minimum value constrained by another set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-number-theory, optimization, maxima-minima

So I recently stumbled upon an interesting problem that asked to find the equation for $\min_{t<x} t^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

I know that $\min_{t} t^2$ describes the minimum of $t^2$ over all possible values of $t$ but I'm not quite sure how to interpret the notation above to find an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$min\{ t^2 : t < x \}$
.....